# Dynaconf error when running from executable file

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, pywebview, dynaconf

## Context

I have a flask application that runs locally. It is just a GUI for another program.
I made it a desktop app by using pywebview and **everything works fine when I run it using my local Python interpreter**.

### Minimal representation of the project structure:

```
src
 ┣ flask_application
 ┃ ┣ configuration
 ┃ ┃ ┣ with_dynaconf.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ app.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
 ┣ desktop.py
 ┗ __init__.py
```

### Starting point of the project is `desktop.py`:

```
import webview
from flask_application.app import create_app

server = create_app()
webview.create_window('my program', server)
webview.start()
```

### `app.py` content is:

```
import flask
from .configuration import with_dynaconf

def create_app():
    app = flask.Flask(__name__)
    # Init the extensions and configurations with dynaconf
    with_dynaconf.init_app(app)
    return app
```

### `with_dynaconf.py` content is:

```
from dynaconf import FlaskDynaconf

def init_app(app):
    FlaskDynaconf(app)
```

## The error

I'm trying to make the project an executable file using pyinstaller.

This is the pyinstaller command I'm running:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --add-data "src/flask_application;flask_application/" --hidden-import "flask" --hidden-import "dynaconf"  "src/desktop.py"
```

When I run the executable I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\desktop.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "exe_root\flask_application\app.py", line 12, in create_app
    with_dynaconf.init_app(app)
  File "exe_root\flask_application\configuration\with_dynaconf.py", line 5, in init_app
    FlaskDynaconf(app)
  File "dynaconf\contrib\flask_dynaconf.py", line 109, in __init__
  File "dynaconf\contrib\flask_dynaconf.py", line 118, in init_app
  File "dynaconf\contrib\flask_dynaconf.py", line 132, in make_config
  File "dynaconf\contrib\flask_dynaconf.py", line 150, in __init__
  File "dynaconf\base.py", line 121, in __getattr__
  File "dynaconf\base.py", line 180, in _setup
  File "dynaconf\base.py", line 262, in __init__
  File "dynaconf\base.py", line 1149, in execute_loaders
  File "dynaconf\loaders\__init__.py", line 47, in default_loader
  File "dynaconf\default_settings.py", line 55, in start_dotenv
  File "dynaconf\base.py", line 1315, in find_file
  File "dynaconf\utils\files.py", line 67, in find_file
  File "dynaconf\utils\files.py", line 14, in _walk_to_root
OSError: Starting path not found
```

### What I've tried

- I already tried to debug the application using my local Python interpreter, but when it gets on `File "dynaconf\base.py", line 120, in __getattr__` the if statement is false and it does not run `File "dynaconf\base.py", line 121, in __getattr__`. This is different from when the exe file is run, which executes `File "dynaconf\base.py", line 121, in __getattr__` and beyond.
- I also tried to remove the `with_dynaconf.init_app(app)` line from `app.py`. It causes the rest of the code to run fine but without all the extensions and configurations.

## Final

At this point, I have no idea what the problem is. Any help is appreciated.
If you need more information just ask and I'll happily provide it.